# Loading Spinner on a Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce

I have an issue implementing a loading spinner on my visualforce page.

I've used actionstatus with a facet but you are always required to use rerender in order for the spinner to appear. I can't use rerender as it refreshes the page and prevents any errors from appearing.

Is there any handy way of implementing the spinner?

```
<apex:page showheader="false" controller="my_controller" doctype="html-5.0">

     <script>
        function myJavascriptFunc()
        {          
            CallApexMethod() ;
        }
    </script>

     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet"></link>

    <apex:form id="devform">

    <apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethod" action="{!submitForm}"/>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
             <img class="logo" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.company_logo)}"/>         
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <h3 class="label-heading">Create a Test Account</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="divider"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <span class="lbl">Already have an account?</span>
                <input class="button" onClick="window.open('https://login.com')" type="button" value="LOGIN" target="_blank" />
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="row group">
                <a class="tooltips"> 
                 <apex:inputText id="u" styleClass="inputMaterial" value="{!username}" required="true" onblur="floatLabel(this,'lblUserName','b')" onfocus="floatLabel(this,'lblUserName','f')"/>  
                  <label id="lblUserName">Username</label>
                    <span class="">
                      <ul class="list">
                        <li>* Must be from 2 to 64 characters long. </li>
                        <li>* Can contain both alphabetical and numeric characters.</li>
                        <li>* Must contain all lowercase characters.</li>
                        <li>* Can contain the following special characters: period, comma, hyphen, underscore, and parentheses.</li>
                        <li>* For example: merchant_com_24</li>
                      </ul>
                </span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="row group">
                <a class="tooltips"> 
                 <apex:inputText id="e"  styleClass="inputMaterial" value="{!emailaddress}" required="true"  onblur="floatLabel(this,'lblemail','b')" onfocus="floatLabel(this,'lblemail','f')"/>             
                <label id="lblemail" class="floating-label">Email</label>
                </a>
            </div>       

          <div class="row">
              <div class="group" style="float:left; width:167px;">
               <a class="tooltips"> 
               <apex:inputSecret required="true" styleClass="text inputMaterial" id="pwd"  style="width:167px;" value="{!password}" onblur="floatLabel(this,'lblpassword','b')" onfocus="floatLabel(this,'lblpassword','f')" />

                <label class="floating-label" id="lblpassword">Password</label>
                <span class="">
                      <ul class="list">
                        <li>* Must be at least 8 characters long. </li>
                        <li>* Must combine both alphabetical and numeric characters (e.g. j8k9b3p).</li> 
                        <li>* Must contain at least one uppercase and one lowercase character.</li>
                      </ul>
                </span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="group" style="float:right; width:198px;">
                          <a class="tooltips"> 
                          <apex:inputSecret required="true" styleClass="inputMaterial" id="cpwd"  style="width:167px;" value="{!confirmpassword}" onblur="floatLabel(this,'lblcpassword','b')" onfocus="floatLabel(this,'lblcpassword','f')"/>
                          <label id="lblcpassword" class="floating-label">Confirm&nbsp;Password</label>
                          </a>

                      </div>
                  <p /><p />                             

            <div class="clear"></div>
            <apex:pageMessage rendered="{!pwcpw}" severity="Error" strength="1" summary="{!$Label.pwnotmatch}"/>
          </div>            

            <div class="row group">
             <a class="tooltips">          
                 <apex:selectList id="sq" onchange="changeMe(this)" style="width: 441px;" styleClass="select inputMaterial" required="true"  value="{!secquestion}" multiselect="false" size="1" onblur="floatLabel(this,'lblsecquestion','b')" onfocus="floatLabel(this,'lblsecquestion','f')" >
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!SecureQuestions}"/>
                  </apex:selectList>
                 <label id="lblsecquestion" class="floating-label">Secret&nbsp;question</label>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="row group">
                <a class="tooltips"> 
                 <apex:inputText id="sa" styleClass="text inputMaterial" value="{!secanswer}" required="true"  onblur="floatLabel(this,'lblsecanswer','b')" onfocus="floatLabel(this,'lblsecanswer','f')"/> 
                <label id="lblsecanswer" class="floating-label">Secret&nbsp;answer</label>
                </a>
            </div>        
            <div class="row group">
             <a class="tooltips">             
                <apex:selectList id="cr" onchange="changeMe(this)" onblur="floatLabel(this,'lblcur','b')" onfocus="floatLabel(this,'lblcur','f')" style="width: 441px;" styleClass="select inputMaterial" required="true"  value="{!currencyselected}" multiselect="false" size="1" >
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!Currencies}"/>
                  </apex:selectList>
                 <label id="lblcur" class="floating-label">Currency</label>
                </a>
            </div>
           <!-- <div align="right">
            <apex:commandButton styleClass="creaccbut" value="CREATE ACCOUNT" action="{!submitForm}" rerender="createaccountstatus" status="createaccountstatus"/>
            </div> <button class="button-large">CREATE ACCOUNT</button> -->
            <div class="row group">
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            <apex:repeat value="{!mErrors}" var="fielderrors" rendered="{!stageNumber!= 0}">
            <Table class="message" id="insertErrors">
            <tr><td>
            <img alt="Error" src="{!$Resource.error}" title="Error"/>
            {!mErrors[fielderrors]}</td></tr> <br/>
            </Table>
            </apex:repeat>

                <input class="button-large" id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" disabled="true" value="CREATE ACCOUNT" onclick="myJavascriptFunc();"/>
            </div>
        </div>
     </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: rerender doesn't refreshes whole page, its used for partial refresh!

Comment: +1 Rahul, just specify an ID to rerender and it will only refresh that component.

Comment: I did but its not rendering my errors (the block in the apex:repeat tag)